# Border should not edge-to-edge with image

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to archive with `CSS` as attached screenshot. Is there any way using `border`property or any other way archive same as attached screenshot? The top-left and bottom-right border should not edge to edge with image. The border bar `(#095B6F`) should not aligned with image.

[image: Trying to Archive]

```html
<style>
  .bordered {
    width: 50%; }

  .bordered .get { 
    border-color: #095B6F;
    border-style: solid;  
    border-width: 20px 20px 0px 0px; }
</style>

<div class="bordered">
   <img src="https://assets.imgix.net/hp/snowshoe.jpg?auto=compress&w=400&h=400" class="get">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate way to do this is with the css box-shadow property:

```css
.bordered {
  width: 50%; }

.bordered .get { 
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 20px -20px #095B6F;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">
   <img src="https://assets.imgix.net/hp/snowshoe.jpg?auto=compress&w=400&h=400" class="get">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add padding to the image, and create the psuedo-border using a background with `linear-gradient`:

```css
.bordered {
  background: linear-gradient(#095B6F, #095B6F) top right/90% 90% no-repeat;
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://assets.imgix.net/hp/snowshoe.jpg?auto=compress&w=400&h=400" class="bordered">
```

If the image is transparent, the gradient will appear behind the picture. In that case, you can use two gradients:

```css
.bordered {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#095B6F, #095B6F) top right/90% 20px,
    linear-gradient(#095B6F, #095B6F) top right/20px 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

body {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/400x400/ff0000,0/333333,255/?text=Sample&font=lobster" class="bordered">
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking. Thank you!

Comment: I've overcomplicated. You should accept @bwig's answer

Comment: Sure! I will make his day (his first answer). Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Target the image class name which is "get" in your case, and put some padding